# How to avoid response body on http 304 in nginx?

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, http-status-code-304, nginx-config

I am using nginx version 1.10.3 to serve files to browser. 
In my server logs I am seeing response body on 304 response. How to avoid that?

Nginx log:

```
"GET /test/testfile.js HTTP/1.1" 304 2476 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36"
```

Because of this, response contains nginx header information in chrome which is weird.

```
{"testconf": "{"testfield":"1","testfield2":"2"}"}HTTP/1.1 
304 Not Modified
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 15 Sep 2018 00:10:27 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 31 Aug 2018 00:49:38 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "4b1190a2-1b642"
Last-Modified: Fri, 31 Aug 2018 00:49:38 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Server: Test
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0

{"testBooleanName":"true", "testLabelName":"label"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my nginx version from 1.10.3 to 1.14.0 which fixed this issue.